# Can I replace a Svelte store with another store without losing my imports

Tags: typescript, firebase, svelte, sveltekit

I have a factory function that creates a svelte store, which is bound to a Firebase Realtime object:

```js
// $lib/firebase.ts
export function realtimeStore<Project>(path: string) {
  let unsubscribe: () => void

  const projectRef = ref(realtimeDB, path)

  const { subscribe } = writable<Project | null>(null, (set) => {
    unsubscribe = onValue(projectRef, (snapshot) => {
      set((snapshot.val() as Project) ?? null)
    })

    return () => unsubscribe()
  })

  return {
    subscribe,
    set: (value: any) => {
      return set(projectRef, value)
    },
    update: () => {},
  }
}

export const project = realtimeStore('projectPath')
```

And in my components I can do stuff like:

```js
<script lang="ts">
  import { project } from '$lib/firebase'

  $project.name = 'new name'
</script>
```

The problem comes when I need `$project` to start pointing to another path, coming from `$page.params.projectId`. I tried with a derived store, but it's read only:

```js
// $lib/firebase.ts
export const project: Readable<Project | null> = derived([selectedProjectId], ([$selectedProjectId], set) => {
  if ($selectedProjectId) {
    return realtimeStore<Project>($selectedProjectId).subscribe(set)
  } else {
    set(null)
  }
})

// If I try to do $project.name = '...' from a component 
// I get an error saying that project doesn't have a "set" function - 
// the store is read only.
```

What is the best way to have a writable `$project` that can also change the path to the realtime object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @parmer_110 suggested, added a `setPath` function to `realtimeStore`:

```js
// $lib/firebase
export function realtimeStore<T>() {
  let unsubscribe: () => void = () => {}
  let objectRef: any

  const store = writable<T | null>(null)
  let storeSet = store.set

  return {
    subscribe: store.subscribe,
    set: (value: any) => {
      return set(objectRef, value)
    },
    update: () => {},
    setPath: (path: string) => {
      objectRef = ref(realtimeDB, path)
      unsubscribe()
      unsubscribe = onValue(objectRef, (snapshot) => {
        storeSet((snapshot.val() as T) ?? null)
      })
    },
  }
}

// Extend the Writable interface to make TypeScript happy
interface TRealtimeDBWritable<T> extends Writable<T> {
  setPath: (path: string) => void
}

// Define our store
export const artboardStore: TRealtimeDBWritable<Artboard | null> = realtimeStore<TArtboard>()
```

To use the store:

```js
// MyComponent.svelte
import { artboardStore } from '$lib/firebase'

artboardStore.setPath('path/to/artboard/1')
$artboardStore.name = 'new name'

// later...

artboardStore.setPath('path/to/artboard/2')
$artboardStore.name = 'new name for other artboard'
```